# Customizing the value of Partition Metrics in Laravel nova

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have a table `users` that has relationship to `operations`.

```
\App\user:

public function operation()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Operation');
    }
```

So I can do:

```
$operation = user->operation
```

Now I want to add a Partition Metric in the Users resource page that tells me the number of users grouped by operation

Right now, it display an id, and it not filtering my users ( need to filter query with `company_id` )

```
public function calculate(NovaRequest $request)
    {
        return $this->count($request, User::class, 'operation_id', 'name');
    }
```

I tried to add `name` column name, but first it is not working, and second, I would need the name of the operation, not the user, so it should be something like `operation.name` but it is not working neither.

How can I print the operation name instead of operation_id

PD: Basically, whole process it being more painful because I can't see the output of `dump()` or `dd()` in a metric, so I can't debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use ->label() method as mentioned in Laravel/nova docs:
https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/metrics/defining-metrics.html#customizing-partition-labels.

Then, the correct code should be:

```
public function calculate(NovaRequest $request)
    {
        return $this->count($request, User::class, 'operation_id')
               ->label(function($operationId){
                 switch($operationId){
                       case 'opration_1_id': return 'operation_1_name';
                       break; 
                       case 'opration_2_id': return 'operation_2_name';
                       break; 
                       default: return 'Other';
                    }
               });
    }
```

Comment: Any time, Welcome :)